# Merge two datasets by partial string - R

Tags: r, string, merge, partial

I have two datasets both with different columns however both with names. I wanted to match the names and concatenate the rows to each other

```
df1 <- data.frame (Name = c("Smith, Carl", "Jones, Allan", "Waterman, Josh", "Woods, Alex"),
 number1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))

df2 <- data.frame(fullname = c("Carl Smith", "Allan Jones", "Josh Waterman", "Alex Woods"),
research = c("genetics", "genetics", "mathematics", "plant"))
```

I would like to combine the dataset into

| Name | Number1 | Research | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith, Carl | 1 | genetics | Carl Smith |
| Jones, Allan | 2 | genetics | Allan Jones |
| Waterman, Josh | 3 | mathematics | Josh Waterman |
| Woods, Alex | 4 | plant | Alex Woods |

I have tried `merge(df1, df2, by.x = "Name", by.y = "fullname", all = TRUE)`
but it doesn't match the partial names, it gives:

| Name | Number1 | Research | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith, Carl | 1 | - | - |
| Jones, Allan | 2 | - | - |
| Waterman, Josh | 3 | - | - |
| Woods, Alex | 4 | - | - |
| - | - | genetics | Carl Smith |
| - | - | genetics | Allan Jones |
| - | - | mathematics | Josh Waterman |
| - | - | plant | Alex Woods |

Comment: Why would you expect `merge()` to match `Smith, Carl` to `Carl Smith`? Is it truly "partial string" or do you need to match `X, Y` to `Y X` exactly?

Comment: Do a search on "fuzzy join"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved by a fuzzy (=not needing perfectly matching conditions) join of both datasets. This is different from merge as it joins two tables based on fuzzy string matching. **Beware that this does not always work perfectly and may produce incorrectly joined rows**. If the join is producing errors, try manipulating the `max_dist` argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df1 %>%
rename(fullname = Name) %>% #fuzzyjoin expects equal colnames
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_inner_join(df2,by = "fullname", method = "jaccard", max_dist=0.31)
```

Comment: Please try to explain the solution